# How to call a custom jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery and I'm trying to create a custom jQuery function. The function will rotate images.  Simple enough!  Here's how I am calling the function at the moment:

```
function rotate(degree) {
    $(this).css({
        "transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Internet Explorer */
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Firefox */
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Safari and Chrome */
        "-o-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)" /* Opera */
    });
}
```

I'd like to call the above function like this:

```
$(".object").rotate(8);
```

**How would I change the above function to work like this?**

Comment: And your question is.. what? As it stands your code doesn't look valid - you're calling a function on an object, but the function isn't a "member" of that object's "type". I think you should do some research on extending jQuery objects.

Comment: The question is in the title

Comment: No, that's not really a question as it doesn't make any sense. You don't "pass" `this` anywhere -- `this` is something automatically available in function contexts. You can pass object references as function arguments (including whatever `this` evaluates to in the calling scope), but that's not what you're doing here.

Comment: `rotate` is not a jQuery method and you cannot call it that way.

Comment: No it's a CSS method and I'm calling it using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `each()`. The jQuery `css()` function works on the entire set, like almost every jQuery function.

Here is (at least close to) the best practice, industry-recognized method of creating new jQuery plugins. The reason that your code was not working is because all you did was declare a global function. To make it so that jQuery objects have access to the function, you have to add the function to the jQuery object itself, so that it will be properly paired with instances of that object, making `this` access the current jQuery set. This is done like the following. The funny stuff in the function wrapping everything is done for various reasons you can read about in most jQuery plugin tutorials online. Note that inside jQuery functions, there is no need to do `$(this)` as `this` already refers to the jQuery matched set.

```
(function($, window, undefined) {
   $.fn.rotate = function(degree) {
      return this.css({
         "transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)",
         "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Internet Explorer */
         "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Firefox */
         "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Safari and Chrome */
         "-o-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)" /* Opera */
      });
   };
   $.fn.unrotate = function() {
      return this.css({
         "transform": "",
         "-ms-transform": "", /* Internet Explorer */
         "-moz-transform": "", /* Firefox */
         "-webkit-transform": "", /* Safari and Chrome */
         "-o-transform": "" /* Opera */
      });          
   };
}(jQuery, window));
```

I added an `unrotate` function so you can remove the css easily as well.

[pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514749/pimvdb) says that jQuery 1.8 will automatically try prefixes, so it may be that you don't need anything but the `transform` property if you're using that version or higher.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.rotate = function(degree){
   this.each(function(){
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Internet Explorer */
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Firefox */
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)", /* Safari and Chrome */
        "-o-transform": "rotate(" + degree + "deg)" /* Opera */
      });
   });
   return this;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: Maybe `return this.each` to keep chaining. And jQuery 1.8 will automatically try prefixes.

Comment: Sigh. I have to stop using my phone to answer questions. It's too slow!

Comment: Just some notes: you don't need `each`... the `css()` function will already operate on every member element of the jQuery array object. Also, there is no need for a separate `return` statement, simply `return this.css(...);` is sufficient.

Comment: Given that jQuery uses the `each` method internally, why would you make your own code more complicated and longer and thus harder to comprehend and maintain?

Comment: The OP did not use `each`. It clutters the code. It's not necessary. It teaches wrong principles to jQuery beginners. It's not how a plugin is usually written. Arguing that "programmers" can maintain it is incomprehensible. Any programmer can write code a computer can understand. It takes a **good** programmer to write code a human can understand.